# Django Bootstrap/Materialize

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

```html
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/Carousel/001.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/Carousel/002.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/Carousel/003.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My bootstrap doesn't work for carousels neither does for Materialize. What could be the problem? Is the Javascript causing problem or what is it? I'm getting broken carousels. Ignore the images in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The class of the `<div>`s around the images must be `carousel-item`, not just `item`. See [the Bootstrap documentation for carousels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).